# How to check if positional indexes in a list exists in section of corresponding DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Date          A      B      C
2021-08-20    1      2      3
2021-08-21    2      3      4
2021-08-22    3      4      5
2021-08-23    4      5      6
2021-08-24    7      8      9
2021-08-25    10     11     12
2021-08-26    11     12     13
2021-08-28    12     13     14
```

My "target" section is dates from 2021-08-21 to 2021-08-24.

Now I have a list of positional indices:

```
A = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new list of indices that correspond to the indices only in my target section, and then find the total number of elements in the new list.

Target answer:

```
new_list = [1, 3, 4]
print(len(new_list))
3
```

I've tried this so far:

```
new_list = []
df_range = df.loc['2021-08-21':'2021-08-24']

for data_idx in A:
    if data_idx == df_range.iloc[data_idx]:
        new_list.append(data_idx)
print(len(new_list))
```

But I get IndexErrors (single positional indexer is out-of-bounds) or Key errors (for a similar attempt). I believe what's erroring is when the program tries to locate the indexes outside of this range?

Thank you in advance and sorry if anything is confusing. I know there should be an easy way to do this but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: The output should be something like [1, 2, 3, 4]. What I'm basically trying to do is that I have a list of positional indexes for anomalous data, and a region in the dataframe that I know should be anomalous. I'm trying to figure out how to get the sum of the anomalies in that particular region.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I was just going to do len(new_list) but I'll add it into the question. Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```py
A = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]

df["tmp"] = range(len(df))
x = df.loc["2021-08-21":"2021-08-24"]
print(x.loc[x["tmp"].isin(A), "tmp"].to_list())
```

Prints:

```py
[1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'Date' is in the index of the dataframe and the datatype is datetime index, then we can use `pd.Index.get_indexer` and use set operations to find intersection.

```
#Copy dataframe from question above
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=[0])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
idx = df.index.get_indexer(pd.date_range('2021-08-21', '2021-08-24', freq='D'))

A = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
overlap = set(A) & set(idx)

print(f'{overlap=} and {len(overlap)=}')
```

Output:

```
overlap={1, 3, 4} and len(overlap)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you're wanting to have a list with corresponding indexes to your `df_range`? If so these two approaches are commonly used for that

```
new_list = []
df_range = df.loc['2021-08-21':'2021-08-24']

for i, v in enumerate(df_range):
    new_list.append(i)
    
    
for i in range(len(df_range)):
    new_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering! The first one works for a dataframe but what happens is that the list indexes start from 0. I'll like to keep the same indexes as the original dataframe (for example, if the first positional index in the original dataframe was 10, what should be added to new_list is 10). I also want to add only the indexes in A to the list -- the A list doesn't have all the indexes of the original dataframe.

Comment: ohh okay I think I understand so in the append statement all you do is `new_list.append(df['Your column'][i]` this goes inside the for loop, and it will grab the value of that column at that index and integrate it into the list, let me know if this works:) btw sorry for taking long to respond